# how to format a burned dvd (r+w)

Tags: 20.04, dvd, sony

hii i want to format a burned dvd in ubuntu....Thus i tried a lot using various options like

```
cdrecord dev=/dev/sr0 blank=fast
```

but its not working error is ( i am using ubuntu 20.04)

```
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Error trying to open /dev/sr0 exclusively (Device or resource busy)... retrying in 1 second.
Error trying to open /dev/sr0 exclusively (Device or resource busy)... retrying in 1 second.
Error trying to open /dev/sr0 exclusively (Device or resource busy)... retrying in 1 second.
Error trying to open /dev/sr0 exclusively (Device or resource busy)... retrying in 1 second.
Error trying to open /dev/sr0 exclusively (Device or resource busy)... giving up.
WARNING: /dev/sr0 seems to be mounted!
wodim: Device or resource busy. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```

can anybody suggest a best solution for formatting the already burned dvd(r+w)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What are you trying to achieve? Which type is the disc you are trying to modify (e.g. DVD+R, DVD-RW)? Are you using `sudo` to access `/dev/sr0` owned by root?

Comment: I have DVD-RW no i am not using sudo

Comment: while doing cdrecord dev=/dev/sr0 blank=fast  wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.
wodim: Some drives do not support all blank types.
wodim: Try again with wodim blank=all.

Comment: i have DVD+RDL 8.5GB RW sony

Comment: I am sorry, DVD+R (DL) discs are not rewritable.

Comment: can i burn .iso image to dvd -r

Comment: Yes but only once to a single disc (not used yet).

Answer (score 0):

"Device or resource busy" sounds like the filesystem on the DVD is mounted, which is also stated in the warning. Do `umount /dev/sr0` before.

Comment: wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.

Comment: unable to format please suggest proper command for doing same

Comment: i have DVD+RDL 8.5GB RW sony

Comment: @lijun, Are you trying `umount` with elevated permissions: `sudo umount /dev/sr0` ?

Comment: yes sir...but not working

Comment: same error even if after using sudo   wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.
wodim: Some drives do not support all blank types.
wodim: Try again with wodim blank=all

Comment: Are you sure that the DVD disks are really re-writable? I searched for the specs via the internet, and I suspect that they are 'write-once' disks.

Comment: ohh...then can i burn the iso image to dvd-r

Comment: Yes, @lijun, but only once. A USB pendrive can be re-written several times.

Comment: You say "same error" and tell us a completely different error message. Since it is a RW disc, it should be erasable. `blank=all` should do it.